# Can someone explain this little piece of code in C?

Tags: c

The output is :

```
25
28ff1c
28ff1c
25
```

I don't understand why. The first value and address are understandable, but why is the second output the same? Doesn't the address of g get changed in the function?

```
float add(int *x, int y)
{
    static float s = 100.f;
    s=s+y;
    x=x+y;
    return s;
}



int main()
{

    int g=25;
    printf("%d\n",g);
    printf("%x\n",&g);

    add(&g,35.2);

    printf("%x\n",&g);
    printf("%d\n",g);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x=x+y;` Did you mean `*x = *x + y;`?

Comment: _Doesn't the address of g get changed in the function?_  No, the pointer `x` gets changed, and that pointer is local to `add` function.

Comment: Inside the `add` function, you're adding `y` to the address of `x`, which is passed in by value, so only the local copy of that address changes. The function can change the *value* at that address if it wants, but it can't change the address (unless you pass it the address of another variable with an `int **`).

Comment: The line `float add(int *x, int y)` was added by an edit from someone else than the OP. I doubt that this line is correct. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Not my edit, but the compiler would complain about `double` passed to `int`.

Comment: Aside: print an address with `printf("%p\n", (void*)&g);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*...but why is the second output the same?*

Because your original code:

```
float add(int *x, int y)
{
    static float s = 100.f;
    s=s+y;
    x=x+y; // changing the pointer
    return s;
}
```

Does not change the value pointed to by the address of x.
Change the code as shown to allow the value to be updated:

```
float add(int *x, int y)
{
    static float s = 100.f;
    s=s+y;
    *x=*x+y; //changing the value pointed to by the pointer
             //(i.e., the value exposed via the de-referenced pointer is 
             //modified to a new value.)
    return s;
}
```

Given:

```
 int g=25;
 ...
 add(&g,35.2);
```

Results after change:

> 25
>   81feb8
>   81feb8
>   60

Note:  Because the type of the 2nd argument: `float add(int *x, int y)`
       is `int`, `35.2` is truncated to `30`, resulting the in the sum being
       `60` instead of `60.2`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the address of a variable with a single pointer (ie int *x).  As suggested in comments this may not have been your intention so sorry if you know this.

To change the address you must use a double pointer, you must deference it once to get the address and to access the value you must deference it twice.

```
void func(int **x)
{
    int value = **x;
    uintptr_t address = *x;

    *x = address + sizeof(int);
}
```

Comment: It depends on whether you are trying to edit the value of an `int *`, or edit the value of an `int`.  in this function, `void SumOfInts(int *a, int b);//adds value of b to a`  called like this:  `int a = 12;  SumOfInts(&a, 10);` will work perfectly to change the value of `a` to `22`.

Comment: That is correct.

As originally written it's unclear what exactly is happening.  The author expresses surprise that the address of g is not changed.  I am addressing under what conditions the address may be changed.  There is no way in the original edit the address of g might be changed.  It does however look like a common mistake which is to forget to deference a double pointer when changing the address of a variable.